# Center of SO(V,q)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quadratic-forms

Let $V$ be finite dimensional vector spaces and $q$ is quadratic form. I'm looking for $Z(SO(V,q))$. where $SO(V,q)$ is special orthogonal group.

If $\operatorname{dim} V$ is odd then $Z(SO(V,q))={I}$ because $-\sigma_u\in SO(V,q) $ where $\sigma_u$ is reflection $$\sigma_u(x)=x-2\frac{b(x,u)}{q(u)}$$
But I couldn't calculate center when $\operatorname{dim} V$ is even.

I have not any idea how to deal with it.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the signature of $q$?  I'm confused about $\sigma_u$ in the case of $q(u) = 0$.

Comment: For example $q$ could be identically zero, in which case ${\rm SO}(V,q) = {\rm GL}(V)$ with centre all scalars. It also depends heavily on the field over which $V$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito the definition reflection $\sigma_u$ is for $q(u)\neq0$

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right.Let $\mathbb F$ be finite field and $char(\mathbb F)\neq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finite fields of odd characteristic, there are two types of quadratic form when $n = {\rm dim} V$ is even and one type when $n$ is odd. When $n>2$, the groups ${\rm SO}(V,q)$ act absolutely irreducibly on $V$, and so only scalar matrices could be in the centre. But for the scalar $\lambda I_n$ to preserve $q$, we need $\lambda^2=1$, so $\lambda = \pm 1$. Hence $Z({\rm SO}(V,q))$ has order 1 when $n$ is odd and 2 when $n$ is even.

When $n=2$, ${\rm SO}(V,q)$ is a cyclic (and hence abelian) group of order $|F|-1$ when the form $q$ has plus-type and $|F|+1$ when $q$ has minus-type.

Comment: I don't understand why only scaler matrices could be in the center.

Comment: It is a consequence of Schur's Lemma in Representation Theory that the centralizer (in the matrix algebra) of the image of an irreducible representation is a division algebra over $F$ and, if the representation is absolutely irreducible, then it consists of scalar matrices only.

Comment: Dear Holk I am looking for solution without Representation theory. May you suggest solution with reflection or something like this